# jDateChooser restricted to only select a specific day of the week

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdatechooser

[image]

Tell me how to make a restriction for choosing by day for the flight that I choose. For example, when I select Paris, only Monday and Wednesday are available for selection throughout the year .

I tried to find information but really did not find where exactly to prescribe the conditions in the gui for this calendar.

Comment: This version of [JCalendar](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/another-jcalendar#readme) allows you to restrict the day of the week.

Comment: Item one, instead of JDateChooser find a date picker that supports [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).